# launch BroardcastReceiver class

Tags: android, class, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, launch

I'm creating a SMS fording app. I currently got two classes; a main Activity class which will be used to modify setting and smsListener class which uses BroardcastReceiver. However, I can not work out how to launch the smsListener class.
Code of smsListener class for ref

```
package sms.pack;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String device = "mobile_num_here"; //number to listen for
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null){
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        if (msg_from == device)
                        {
                            savedata(msgBody);
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }               
            }
        }
    }
    public void savedata(String data)
    {
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (root.canWrite()){
                File gpxfile = new File(root, "smsfile.txt");//remember change directory
                FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
                out.write(data);
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(data,"Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I was planing to use intent to launch be that is not working, method below

```
public void startListening(View view)
{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("sms.pack","sms.pack.SmsListener");
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use startActivity to launch an Activity.
A [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) listens for broadcasted intents.  Use sendBroadcast(intentToBroadcast).  Make sure you put a [receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver) tag in your manifest file.

Comment: 'code' Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("sms.pack","sms.pack.SmsListener");
    sendBroadcast(i);

This does appear to work however when debug i =  sms.pack.SMS_forwardActivity.startListening(View)

where I would thank i should equal  sms.pack.startLister

any how on testing I do not get a saved file when debuging the debug does not enter the StartLister class. Any idea as to why? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must register your broadcast receiver first.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity ....
    </activity>
    <receiver  android:name="SmsListener ">
        <intent-filter  android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Start your broadcast receiver by:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(your_Activity_Class.this, SmsListener.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Hope this help.